# Constant solution of Euler-Cauchy equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I want to prove that if $u \in C^2([-1, 1])$ solves
$$
x^2 u''(x) + 2xu'(x) = 0
$$
on $[-1, 1]$, then $u$ is constant. Is this possible without using arguments from ODE theory, i.e. Picard-Lindelöf's theorem or explicitly calculating solutions?

So far I tried to partially integrate
$$
0 = \int^1_{-1} x^2u''(x)+2xu'(x) ~\mathrm{d}x
$$
which did not help me that much...

Comment: Why don't you want to solve it ? It's very easy to solve. Solution are of the form $u(x)=C+D/x$. And thus, if $u\in \mathcal C^2[-1,1],$ then $D=0$.

Comment: Maybe you could show me how you solved it... . I just want to make sure that I can prove that ALL solutions are of this form.

Comment: $$x^{2}u'' + 2xu' = (x^{2}u')' = 0 \implies ...$$ Also, [this might help to prove it without solving explicitly.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the equation can be written as
$$ (x^2u'(x))'=0 $$
by using product-rule. So
$$ x^2u'(x)=C $$
which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

Set $v(x)=u'(x)$. Then if $a\neq 0$ (suppose WLOG that $a>0$) is s.t. $v(a)\neq 0$ (suppose WLOG that $v(a)>0$), there is $\delta >0$ s.t. $v(x)>0$ for all $x\in (a-\delta ,a+\delta )$ where $a-\delta >0$. Then, for all $x\in (a-\delta ,a+\delta )$,

\begin{align*}
x^2u''(x)+2xu'(x)=0&\iff x^2v'(x)+2xv(x)=0\\
&\iff \frac{v'(x)}{v(x)}=-\frac{2}{x}\\
&\iff \ln(v(x))=\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+C\\
&\iff v(x)=\frac{D}{x^2}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, $u(x)=C+\frac{D}{x},$ where $C$ and $D$ are constant. You can prolonge $(a-\delta ,a+\delta )$ to $(0,\infty )$ if $a>0$ and $(-\infty ,0)$ if $a<0$.

**Method 2**

Suppose $x\neq 0$ (suppose WLOG $x>0$). Then, using an integrating factor yields
\begin{align*}
x^2u''(x)+2xu'(x)=0&\iff u''(x)+\frac{2}{x}u'(x)=0\\
&\iff u''(x)e^{2\ln(x)}+\frac{2}{x}u'(x)e^{\frac{2}{x}}=0\\
&\iff \left(u'(x)e^{2\ln(x)}\right)'=0\\
&\iff u'(x)e^{2\ln(x)}=C\\
&\iff u'(x)=Ce^{-2\ln(x)}\\
&\iff u'(x)=\frac{C}{x^2}\\
&\iff u(x)=D+\frac{C}{x}.
\end{align*}